# Why is my python code not writing to MYSQL database, using utility code file

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I am seeking help my goal is for an update loop for my databases for my discord bot. However, it just refuses to write to the database, but the loops will run. What am I doing wrong?

I know that it worked somewhat before, but as of this point, it doesn't write to the database.

```
import mysql.connector

from util.db_tools import connect, execute, execute_data_input, close
from mysql.connector import errorcode


class tasks(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.index = 0
        self.update.start()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def update(self):
        print("Updating...")
        async for guild in self.client.fetch_guilds():
            channels = await guild.fetch_channels()
            members = await guild.fetch_members().flatten()
            channel_count = len(channels)
            members_count = len(members)
            update_date = datetime.now()
            # add data to stats table
            bans = await guild.bans()
            ban_count = len(bans)
            # To add new row each day
            add_bans = ("INSERT INTO stats"
                        "(member_count, bans)"
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)"
                        )
            data_bans = (members_count, ban_count)
            connect(guild.id)
            logging = (
                '''
                INSERT INTO logging (server, message_edit, message_deletion=, role_changes, name_update, member_movement, avatar_changes, bans, ignored_channels) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                '''
            )
            data = (str(guild.id), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None)
            execute_data_input(logging, data)
            execute_data_input(add_bans, data_bans)
            close()
            async for member in guild.fetch_members():
                member_id = member.id
                displayName = member.display_name
                discriminator = member.discriminator
                mention = member.mention
                # update existing
                User = discord.Member
                dm = User.dm_channel
                # Updates the following info daily
                update_user = (
                    "UPDATE users SET display_name='{}', discriminator='{}', mention='{}', dm_channel='{}', server='{}', id='{}', names='{}' WHERE user_id='{}'".format(
                        displayName, discriminator, mention, dm, guild.name, member.id, str(displayName), member_id))
                update_Guild = (
                    "UPDATE servers SET prefix='{}', id='{}', Member_Count='{}', Channels='{}', Last_Update='{}' WHERE Server_ID='{}'".format(
                        PREFIX, guild.id, members_count, channel_count, update_date, guild.id))
                connect(guild.id)
                execute(update_user)
                close()
                connect("discord")
                execute(update_Guild)
                close()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(tasks(client))
```

The part I need help with is the @ tasks loop.

I know the connection to the MySQL server is there because my utility code returns

```
 Connected to MySQL Server version  5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
 You're connected to database:  ('793077301935865876',)
 Connection Closed.
```

in the console. Which correct me if I am wrong, but that means it is MySQL script that is wrong somehow. Though I am unsure of how to fix what is happening.

util.db_tools

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import sys


def exists():
    File = open("data_bool.txt", "r")
    return File.read()


def write(ctx):
    File = open("data_bool.txt", "w")
    File.write(ctx)


def connect(self):
    global cnx
    global cursor
    try:
        database_name = self
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='192.168.86.41',
            user='admin',
            password='Shellshocker93!',
            database=f"{database_name}"
        )
    # exception occurred
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Something is wrong with your user name or password')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Database does not exist')
        else:
            print(f'\033[1;31m {err}')

    if cnx.is_connected():
        db_Info = cnx.get_server_info()
        print(f'\033[1;32m Connected to MySQL Server version\033[0;33m ', db_Info)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record1 = cursor.fetchone()
        record =record1[0]
        print(f'\033[1;32m You\'re connected to database: \033[3;34m', record)


def fetchall():
    cursor.fetchall()


def execute(ctx):
    try:
        write('False')
        cursor.execute(ctx, multi=True)
        cnx.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Something is wrong with your user name or password')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Database does not exist')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_DUP_ENTRY:
            print(f'\033[1;32m Entry already exists.')
            write('True ')
            return
        else:
            print(f'{err}\n' + f"{ctx}")


def execute_data_input(ctx, ctx1):
    try:
        write('False')
        cursor.execute(ctx, ctx1, multi=True)
        cnx.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Something is wrong with your user name or password')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print(f'\033[1;31m Database does not exist')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_DUP_ENTRY:
            print(f'\033[1;32m entry already exists.')
            write('True ')
            return
        else:
            print(f'{err}\n' + f"{ctx} \n {ctx1}")


def close():
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    print(f"\033[0;32m Connection Closed. \n")


def commit():
    cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Could you post a [mre]? If you're having a MySQL problem, the Discord stuff is probably not relevant and just clutters up the question.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `INSERT INTO IF NOT EXISTS`. Use `INSERT IGNORE` to ignore duplicate keys.

Comment: ok will do but iI just minimized it to bare minimum

Comment: You removed all the utility code that the question is about!

Comment: replaced utility code, though I am unsure it's the utility code it worked when I had this code done differently outside of a discord.py cog.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `self` as an ordinary parameter name. It's conventionally the name of the first argument to class methods. I was trying to find the `class` definition when I saw that. Why not `def connect(database_name):`?

Comment: You should use queries with parameters rather than formatting them as strings. You even have a function for that: `execute_data_input()`.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reasons why nothing would be written to the DB. Add a `print()` statement to `execute()` and `execute_data_input()` so you can tell if they'r being called.

Comment: ok, now it throws a syntax error with:

`execute(
                f'''
                INSERT INTO logging server='{str(guild.id)}', message_edit='{0}', message_deletion='{0}', role_changes='{0}', name_update='{0}', member_movement='{0}', avatar_changes='{0}', bans='{0}'
                '''
            )`

Comment: If adding print statements caused a syntax error, you probably have a missing parenthesis.

Comment: Why are you using f-strings? Use statements with parameters and `execute_data_input()`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `str()` in f-strings. It automatically converts things to strings.

Comment: I will give that a shot then

Comment: It's not going to make a difference to the actual problem, though. It's just better coding.

Comment: welp it did fix i just have to solve why my insert into logging does not wright to the db now, my table for logging is still empty Scratch that it was my syntax. thank you for the help